# Software to create frames animation in one image

Tags: animation, 2d

I want to create 2D animation in SFML.
The best idea is to create one image divided by squares. Each square in x axis will be animation sequence.
i.e. image divided by 10x10 is 100 frames of animation.

What software will be best to create that type of image (need to edit each frame separately and add moving effect, motion-blur and oter, I need to see all frames at once)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever suits you and your project needs.

If you're using some technical entities, then you might want to create actual 3D models and render different settings etc. For that you could use essentially any 3D modeling software. As supporter of free software, I'd suggest to use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).

If you want to stay in the 2D world, then you'll mostly always end up with the answers [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/).

If you want something specialized your best starting point would then be [Google](https://www.google.ch/search?q=google%20sprite%20animation%20software).